# Executing wmv file packaged in jar

Tags: java, netbeans, getresource

I want to execute the wmv video file present in PicturePackage.
i am using following code:

```
try {
        File f;
        f = new File(getClass().getResource("/PicturePackage/admin_input.wmv").toURI());
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Help.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

This code runs and plays video when I run in netbeans. But when i execute it via jar file build by netbeans, it does not run the video file.
Any specific issue I am not taking care of???

EDIT:

I tried this one

```
File tempFile = null;
try (InputStream in =
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PicturePackage/admin_input.wmv")) {
Path temp = Files.createTempFile("temp", ".wmv");
Files.copy(in, temp);
tempFile = temp.toFile();
// This will try to delete the file when you close your java app
tempFile.deleteOnExit(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
// Handle the exceptions properly
}

// Here you can use tempFile to open it
if (tempFile != null) {
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
}
```

And this is the stacktrace I get

java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\Ashu\AppData\Local\Temp\temp1136027223125637051.wmv
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:81)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2841)
    at gatetestadmin.Help.jButton1ActionPerformed(Help.java:148)
    at gatetestadmin.Help.access$000(Help.java:23)
    at gatetestadmin.Help$1.actionPerformed(Help.java:63)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Just for asking, is your video really packaged into your jar file ?

Comment: yup, i have checked it via 7zip. Video file is present in jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run it from Netbeans, your wmv file exists as a separate, independent file. This can be played by an external video player.

When you package your application into a jar and run it as a jar, the wmv will be packed into the jar, and the `f` file you create will refer to that jar entry. This jar entry will not be available/interpretable to an external video player.

You have to extract the wmv, save it as a temporary file and open that. Or don't include the video file in the jar, place it next to the jar.

Here's how you can extract the video to a temporary file:

```
File tempFile = null;
try (InputStream in =
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PicturePackage/admin_input.wmv")) {
    Path temp = Files.createTempFile("temp", ".wmv");
    Files.copy(in, temp, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    tempFile = temp.toFile();
    // This will try to delete the file when you close your java app
    tempFile.deleteOnExit(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle the exceptions properly
}

// Here you can use tempFile to open it
if (tempFile != null) {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to run the file in jar. If not, then how can we "extract" from the jar??? Thanks for your conncern

Comment: External video players typically do not support playing a video file packed in a zip or jar file, so I woudn't count on that. Easiest would be not to pack the video in the jar, simply place it next to the jar file.

Comment: Edited to show how to extract the video to a temp file.

Comment: Not working. I used JoptionPane to get the exception. It says FileAlreadyExist Exception. Despite I deleted all files in temp folder

Comment: `Files.createTempFile()` generates a unique, non-existent file. Please post your stack trace because it is unclear for me where the exception occurs.

Comment: How do I write stack trace in comments. it allows only 600 characters and stack trace is pretty large...

Comment: Add it to your question for example.

Comment: Added to the question the complete output of e.printstacktrace(). I guess the problem comes in copying the file because temp file is already created during createtempfile()

Comment: I added Files.delete(temp); after Path path line and it starts working.

Comment: Ah, now I know. Obviously `createTempFile()` creates the file, so we have to tell the `Files.copy()` to overwrite that with the option: `REPLACE_EXISTING`. Edited.

Comment: Thanks icza, that works. Meanwhile I found another code and want to know which one would be better

Comment: String temppath= System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\admin_input.wmv";
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PicturePackage/admin_input.wmv");
File f= new File(temppath);
try {
            OutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len = in.read(buffer);
            while (len != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = in.read(buffer);
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    throw new InterruptedException();
        }
    }
}

Comment: My solution is simpler and more efficient, use mine.